What are the conditions for a Force Bonus skipping a mission requirement?
Sometimes when completing a quest, I'll get credit for completing an optional mission requirement even if I didn't meet said requirement with the message "Force Bonus". For example, in the video below I get credit for the "Clear with a Fire-affinity main weapon" mission even though my characters were using Water-affinity weapons.
Why are missions sometimes marked as cleared when I didn't meet the requirements? What are the conditions for a Force Bonus? Does it have something to do with the total force of my deck being higher than the suggested force?




According to Reddit:

When your force is higher than recommended by 30k+ it will automatically complete all stage missions, e.g. use companion skill, use character skill...

That's why you got "Clear with a Fire-affinity main weapon" without using fire weapons.
